# JavaFX combobox css styling

Tags: css, button, combobox, javafx, styling

I'm trying to customize a combo box in JavaFX through css. I can't customize the "arrow button" on the right (I want it to disappear, or to have a custom graphic, for example).

I have been checking the default [caspian.css](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/2.2/master/rt/raw-file/tip/javafx-ui-controls/src/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/caspian/caspian.css), but no matter what modifications I do to the .combo-box section, the arrow button is not affected.

Any idea of where this can be edited?

Comment: searching more information, i can achive some changes trough .combo-box .arrow{...} and  .combo-box .arrow-button {...} classes

Answer (score 6):

Using the following `CSS` in the style sheet will get rid of all of the `ComboBox` arrows

```
.combo-box .arrow, .combo-box .arrow-button{
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Haven't had the chance to try it out, let me know if it does though

Comment: Yup it works in Java 8 with JavaFX-2 for me, looking at `modena.css` is bit misleading here

Answer (score 4):

Use the *CSS Analyser* option in Scenebuilder to get the CSS of any node that you want to play with
[image]

After that just select any node and you'll see all the classes which you can modify using CSS.

[image]
[image]

Now that I know the class I can make my changes accordingly in my `CSS` file

```
.combo-box{
    -fx-border-color:#E6E6E6;
    -fx-border-style:solid;
    -fx-border-width:1;
}
.combo-box .arrow{
    -fx-background-color:#2478E9;
}
.combo-box .arrow-button{
    -fx-background-color:white;
    -fx-border-style:none;
}
.combo-box .arrow-button{
    -fx-background-color:white;
}
.combo-box .list-cell{
    -fx-background-color:white;
}
```

Which gives me an end result like this.
[image]

For more advanced analysis of CSS and other Events occurring when the application is running, you can try [Scenic View](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/).

Comment: Thanks for the hint for the css analyzer. Didn´t know that feature. Saves my live!

Answer (score 0):

I wanted it to disappear too. But nothing worked for me on javafx 8 until I tried the following:
    css:`.combo-box.REFERENCEDONLY .arrow-button {
        -fx-padding: 0 0 0 -7;
    }`

basically it says: use negative padding on the arrow-button's left side to effectively shrink it.

javafx code:`myCombobox.getStyleClass().add("REFERENCEDONLY");`